# JS. Как узнать встречается ли два парных тега в строке?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio

Столкнулся с проблемой. Написал код, он работает, но частично:

```
let Str = "<p>Первый параграф</p><p>Второй параграф</p>";
if (Str.includes("<p>") && Str.includes("</p>")) {
  console.log(true);
} else {
  console.log(false);
}
```

При тесте выдает true. Но если возьмем неповторяющийся парный тег:

```
let Str = "<p>Один параграф</p>"
```

Он также будет выдавать true, а должен выдавать false.
Как можно сделать проверку?

Если в Str 2 раза встречается парные теги`<p></p><p></p>`должен быть true. Если в Str парные теги встречаются только один раз `<p></p>`- false.

Comment: что именно вы подразумеваете под выражением «неповторяющийся парный тег»? и почему вы его противопставляете (судя по общему смыслу изложения) выражению «два парных тега»? `<p>` и `</p>` — это же парные теги, правильно? `<p></p>` — это же два парных тега, правильно? // внесите уточнение прямо в текст вопроса, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам нужен метод, который не просто найдет какое-то вхождение, а посчитает их количество. Для этого можно использовать регулярные выражения.

```js
let pattern = /<p>/gi

let str1 = "<p>Первый параграф</p><p>Второй параграф</p>";
if ((str1.match(pattern) || []).length > 1) {
  console.log(true);
} else {
  console.log(false);
}

let str2 = "<p>Первый параграф</p>";
if ((str2.match(pattern) || []).length > 1) {
  console.log(true);
} else {
  console.log(false);
}
```